# Can't install scrot on pi zero

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to install scrot to take screenshots on a pi zero using rapberry pi OS.
I got the command $sudo apt-get install scrot from https://www.imore.com/how-take-screenshot-raspberry-pi no.2 How to download and install Scrot

has this changed?

Comment: So what's the problem. Add any error messages to your question. And isn't scrot pre-installed on PiOS these days? Which OS version do you run this on?

Comment: Yes I think as Scrot is pre-installed that was the problem.. I installed GI  $MP instead with $apt-get install gimp and ran it with just $ gimp all works fine